# Are dogs allowed on the Trans-Siberian railway?

Tags: trans-siberian, pets, regulations

There's a couple of guys from France here in my hostel in Tbilisi with a couple of huskies (or similar dogs).

Their plan is to travel to Russia from here then take the Trans-Siberian to Mongolia.

But a bit of Internet searching turns up nothing real about whether they'll be able to take their dogs on this train or what special rules and regulations might apply.

I realize the Trans-Siberian isn't just a single railway but made up of smaller ones so I suppose there is some chance the rules might vary from one part to the next.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no changes in rules, because the carrier is the same - [RZD](http://eng.rzd.ru/).

About the dog transit rules:
**You must have all medical information about pet, and you must pay for additional ticket. Also you must honor the sanitary rules in the train you are using.**

There are two options for this transit - and it depends on size of the dog.

**For small dogs** the rules are very simple - you put it in the special container and it counts as your luggage and you can borrow it to 1st class and 2nd class (you cannot book sleeping wagons and business class trains).

**For big dogs** the situation is more about the money you will spend for the transit:
Options you have:

- Special not-in-use box in the first wagon of the train.
- Fully-paid room (4 tickets) in 1st class (you cannot book sleeping wagons and business class trains).

[Link in Russian](http://pass.rzd.ru/isvp/public/pass?STRUCTURE_ID=5116)

[The only link in English](http://eng.rzd.ru/isvp/public/rzdeng?STRUCTURE_ID=4144&layer_id=4516&id=2303) about transporting animals in trains (not very applicable for the Trans-Siberian, but better than nothing):

> - Passengers may transport pets if such transportation is not prohibited by vets, customs or other regulations of the Russian Federation and the Republic of Finland.
> - Passengers may take no more than two dogs on a leash or not more than two cages or one dog on a leash and one cage. Cages must be 60x45x25 cm maximum. Several animals may be taken in one cage.
> - Animals must not be placed in carriage aisles or vestibules.
> - Passengers travelling with pets are responsible for their animal(s) and for any inconvenience or damage caused by animals.
> - Animals are prohibited in first class carriages

Comment: VMAtm will probably hug hippietrail for FINALLY asking a Russia-related question here after AGES.

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee It is a nice present for the Birthday (26 November). And I can make a tour for the ST.Petersburg if any will be here during travelling.

Comment: It's a shame this started a month AFTER I was in St P - would have been cool to say hi!

Comment: This is not my first Russia question d-;

Comment: @Mark Mayo Don't be upset - a month ago I wouldn't even read your message on time. And you always can get here another time :)

Comment: No no, I meant Travel.SE started a month too late - I was in St P around the week of June 16 (the night of the free Sting concert!)

Comment: @Mark Mayo You can came here to the RHCP concert :)